# AlertDialogBox is not entering any value in android

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-alertdialog

In my `AlertDialog` box I am using an `EditText` but when I enter any value in the `EditText` I do not get any value.

I have used `setcancelebletouchmode` to true, but I didn't get any value in the `EditText`.

I have set inputtype to number but when I enter any number I don't get any value or is any value displayed in the `EditText`.

**Here is my code:**

```
LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(this);
//Creating a view to get the dialog box
View confirmDialog = li.inflate(R.layout.layout_forlogin, null);

//Initizliaing confirm button fo dialog box and edittext of dialog box
btnconfirmmobile = (Button) confirmDialog.findViewById(R.id.btnlogin);
Mobile = (EditText) confirmDialog.findViewById(R.id.etlogin);

//Creating an alertdialog builder
final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

//Adding our dialog box to the view of alert dialog
alert.setView(confirmDialog);

//Creating an alert dialog
final AlertDialog alertDialog = alert.create();

//Displaying the alert dialog
alertDialog.show();


//On the click of the confirm button from alert dialog
btnconfirmmobile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Hiding the alert dialog

        mobileconfirm = Mobile.getText().toString();

        if (mobileconfirm.equals("")) {
            Mobile.setError("Mobile no can not be blank");

        } else {

            new PostAsyncslogin().execute(mobileconfirm);
            //Getting the user entered otp from edittext
        }

    }
});
alertDialog.setOnKeyListener(new Dialog.OnKeyListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onKey(DialogInterface arg0, int keyCode,
    KeyEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            finish();
            alertDialog.dismiss();
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Here is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"

    android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/bgdialog"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Enter Your Mobile"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#000" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etlogin"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="10">

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnlogin"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="8"
                android:text=" Login "
                android:textColor="#000" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btncancel"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:ems="8"
                android:text=" Cancel "
                android:textColor="#000" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Change from true to false on your key listener**. You should return true if the listener have consumed the event and false otherwise. Just return false and let the framework handle the rest for you. Please see [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.OnKeyListener.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and it worked.I think the problem is not here. You can log mobileConfirm to see its value in else statement.Just put 
Log.e("mobileconfirm", mobileconfirm) in else statement

Answer (score 0):

Try TextInputLayout for show error and get text from edit test box. For ex:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
android:id="@+id/tillogin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etlogin"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="10">
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Your java code:

```
           LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(this);
            //Creating a view to get the dialog box
            View confirmDialog = li.inflate(R.layout.layout_forlogin, null);

            //Initizliaing confirm button fo dialog box and edittext of dialog box
            btnconfirmmobile = (Button) confirmDialog.findViewById(R.id.btnlogin);
          EditText  mobileno = (EditText) confirmDialog.findViewById(R.id.etlogin);
          TextInputLayout  mobilenoError = (TextInputLayout) confirmDialog.findViewById(R.id.tillogin);

            //Creating an alertdialog builder
            final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

            //Adding our dialog box to the view of alert dialog
            alert.setView(confirmDialog);

            //Creating an alert dialog
            final AlertDialog alertDialog = alert.create();

            //Displaying the alert dialog
            alertDialog.show();


            //On the click of the confirm button from alert dialog
            btnconfirmmobile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //Hiding the alert dialog

                    mobileconfirm = mobileno.getText().toString();

                    if (mobileconfirm.equals("")) {
                        mobilenoError.setError("Mobile no can not be blank");

                    } else {

                        new PostAsyncslogin().execute(mobileconfirm);
                        //Getting the user entered otp from edittext
                    }

                }
            });
            alertDialog.setOnKeyListener(new Dialog.OnKeyListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onKey(DialogInterface arg0, int keyCode,
                                     KeyEvent event) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                        finish();
                        alertDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

I hope this may help you,All the best.